# How to remove "View full screen to exit" message on Android 13 version by code

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-13

How to remove "View full screen to exit" message on Android 13 version.I am working on Mobile pos (MPOS APP) and my android application must be in full screen mode , the application is comming in full view mode but always this message "View full screen to exit" appears so how can hide that message complelety   i tried this but not working

```
   private void hideSystemUI(WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController) {
    // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar.
    if (windowInsetsController != null) {
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
    }
}
```

Comment: Modify your firmware to remove the message